Angular/NX - VSCode acknowledges local tsconfig.json, but when building it, the error persists
So, I have a big Angular application which works with NX. This is the project structure:

We have a global tsconfig.base.json with "strict: false". My task is, to set it to "true" and make it compilable. After activating the strict flag, the build crashes obviously, and I started fixing the errors like "string might be undefined here" and so on.
Then I stumpled upon some errors which are very complicated and sensitive to solve, so I wanted the strict build to skip these specific features/modules.
Here is a feature I'd like to silence (so that it is not strict and runs normally again):

There are some strict problems with the reducer.
So this is my local tsconfig.json file:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2022",
    "useDefineForClassFields": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noImplicitOverride": true,
    "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "strict": false  -----> This is what I added
  },
  "files": [],
  "include": [],
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.lib.json"
    },
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.spec.json"
    }
  ],
  "extends": "../../../../tsconfig.base.json",
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true
  }
}

So after adding "strict: false" to my local file, the errors in the reducer file disappear, but when building, the console shows the error is still there.
This is the global tsconfig.base.json:
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": ".",
    "strict": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "esnext",
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
    "lib": ["es2017", "dom"],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": ....(very much)
    }},
    "exclude": ["node_modules", "tmp"]
    }

Why isnt the local tsconfig.json fully applied when building?
